# How much portion of the given text will be displayed in given Size

Tags: ios, nsstring, drawing, uilabel, cgrect

To get the part of the NSString which is displayed in the view.

Or

To get the NSString which can be displayed in the given CGRect.

It returns the string which is displayed on the view (UIlabel, UITextFiled etc).
This is useful when the string to large and view is not long enough to display the whole string.

So i have written the code and added it here.

Answer (score 0):

```
//If you want the string displayed in any given rect, use the following code..
@implementation NSString (displayedString)

//font- font of the text to be displayed
//size - Size in which we are displaying the text

-(NSString *) displayedString:(CGSize)size font:(UIFont *)font
{
NSString *written = @"";

int i = 0;
int currentWidth = 0;
NSString *nextSetOfString = @"";

while (1)
{
    NSRange range;
    range.location = i;
    range.length = 1;

    NSString *nextChar = [self substringWithRange:range];
    nextSetOfString = [nextSetOfString stringByAppendingString:nextChar];

    CGSize requiredSize = [nextSetOfString sizeWithFont:font constrainedToSize:CGSizeMake(NSIntegerMax, NSIntegerMax)];
    currentWidth = requiredSize.width;

    if(size.width >= currentWidth && size.height >= requiredSize.height)
    {
        written = [written stringByAppendingString:nextChar];
    }
    else
    {
        break;
    }
    i++;
}


    return written;
}

@end
```